# Are python decorators invoke the returned callback immediately?

Tags: python, callback, decorator, python-decorators

I am trying to understand decorators behavior by doing some experiments. I am not able to find any doc on what I am seeing, so may be someone can point me to something.

Here is the code using a decorator:

```
def register():
    def func_wrapper(func):
        print 'registered'
    return func_wrapper

@register()
def main_page_func():
    pass
```

When you run this code, you will get the word "registered" printed out:

```
registered
```

This is presumably the equivalent(?) code without decorator:

```
def register(func):
    def func_wrapper():
        print 'registered'
    return func_wrapper


def main_page_func():
    pass

main_page_func = register(main_page_func)
```

When you run the above, nothing gets printed out. I understand this case: *func_wrapper* callback is returned.

However, I am still struggling with the first case that uses decorator: Why is *print* statement being invoked given that *main_page_func* is never being called?

Thanks.

Comment: Change `@register()` to `@register` and `def register():` (in the first example) to something like `def register(f):` and `func_wrapper(func)` (in the first example) to `func_wrapper()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say,

```
@register()
```

it actually calls the function `register()` and the return value is used there, which will be `func_wrapper`, which accepts a function object as input. So, what you have done is

```
@func_wrapper
def main_page_func():
    pass
```

And when you decorate it like this,

```
main_page_func = func_wrapper(main_page_func)
```

`func_wrapper` is invoked and that is why the `registered` is getting printed.

To actually fix this, you need to pass the function object to `register` itself, like in your second example,

```
def register(func):         # func should be here
    def func_wrapper():     # not here
        print 'registered'
    return func_wrapper


@register                   # no parens after `register`
def main_page_func():
    pass
```

Now, the evaluation is like this

```
main_page_func = register(main_page_func)
```

Since the `func_wrapper` is not yet executed, you will not see `registered` getting printed, yet.

Answer (score 1):

Erase the parentheses after the decorator and it will work just as you expect it to.

Also, your register function should take the argument func, but not neccessarily your inner function.